# calculate in how many days work get done

Tags: algebra-precalculus

John completes a work in 10 days when his work efficiency decreases by 19% each day. now If work is increased by 90% and now his efficiency decreases by 10% each day how many days he will take to complete this task.

I tried direct approach geometrical series etc but calculations got rough and calculator is not allowed.

Answer is 20 , so you might wanna reverse engineer it to understand question.my guess is we some how have to use first result to compute it.

sorry about tag i cant find suitable

Comment: Geometric series is the right approach. Please show us the work that you did.  It doesn't matter if it's incomplete, or even if it's wrong.  If we can see what you did we can give you better help.

Comment: I changed the tag from sequences-and-series, which relates to calculus, to a more appropriate one.

Comment: What were your calculations?

Comment: I´ve voted to close since you are not willing to show your calculations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let the work he gets done in a day be x, as per the other answer.

Then, the work he gets done every one of the next days would be x*(0.81)^t.

By geometric series, the total amount of work he has done in 10 days would be x * (1-0.81^10)/(1-0.81).

Let this amount of work be d.

But in this next scenario, the dude does 0.9 times as much work each day and his work is (1+0.9) times as much.

Why is this special? Because 0.9^2 = 0.81

So now if we have x(1 + 0.9 + 0.81 + 0.9*0.81 + 0.81^2 + 0.9*0.81^2+ 0.81^3...) = d(1+0.9)

Well you saw where that went, and that’s why the answer is exactly 20 days.

Comment: Little sloppy but the gist is there +1

Comment: Have you ever heard about Mathjax? It looks horrible.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x$ be work efficiency, which has units of work done/day. From your first sentence, you can calculate a numerical value for $x$. Then you can use $x$ to find what the second sentence asks for. The key relationship here is work efficiency x time = work done.

Comment: i used calculator got almost six days in answer. you see a friend of mine asked this  over phone .then i asked him for solution he send something like this .                     100  81 72.9....................... then 100+90  90+81 81+72.9.......... so answer is 20 i didnt get it